# SQLAlchemy: No module named 'mysql'

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have created this very simple script that connects with SQLAlchemy to a MySQL database and runs a SELECT statement. It works great on my dev laptop. Now that I moved it to a new server, it breaks.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd


def return_connection_string(database_name, database_user, database_password, database_host, database_port):
    try:
        connection_string = 'mysql+mysqlconnector://' + database_user + ':' + \
            database_password + '@' + database_host + ':' + database_port + '/' + database_name
        print(connection_string)
        return connection_string
    except Exception as e:
        print('Encountered error while generating connection string for MySQL!')
        print(e)


def return_connection_object(database_name, database_user, database_password, database_host, database_port):
    try:
        connection_string = return_connection_string(
            database_name, database_user, database_password, database_host, database_port)
        engine = create_engine(connection_string).connect()
        return engine
    except Exception as e:
        print('Encountered error while connecting to MySQL database!')
        print(e)


mysql_conn = return_connection_object(
    'xyz', 'xyz', 'xyz', 'xyz', 'xyz')


SQL_Query = pd.read_sql_query(
    'select current_date as today, current_date-1 as yesterday', mysql_conn)

df = pd.DataFrame(SQL_Query, columns=['today', 'yesterday'])

df1 = df[['yesterday']]

print(df1)

mysql_conn.close()
```

At runtime, the script fails with this error

```
Encountered error while connecting to MySQL database!
No module named 'mysql'
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor'
```

I compared my server against my dev laptop and PIP shows me the same version of SQLAlchemy module: 1.3.11.

Do I need to install another module? What am I missing?

Comment: Can you fix your indentation?

Comment: `SQLAlchemy` doesn't access database directly but uses other modules to work with different databases. And you need some of module which works with `mysql` - ie. `mysql-connector-python` or check what module shows your `pip`

Comment: @furas The server does not have `mysql-connector-python module`. I'll check and report back.

Answer (score 6):

After reviewing the output of PIP on my server and my dev laptop, I discovered that one module was missing. Running this command

```
pip3 install --upgrade mysql-connector-python
```

solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you need to install mysql-connector-python

do `pip install mysql-connector-python`